# specifying multiple key value pairs in 1 cookie string

Tags: cookies

I am trying to create a cookie for my webpage as follows:

```
document.cookie = "Name="+escape(name)+"; Value="+escape(value)+expires+";";
```

name,value being passed to the function and expires is being calculated on the days parameter - which is also passed to this function.

The cookie is being set as a result but the problem is that only one of the parameters are getting set in the cookie. When I try to retrieve the value of document.cookie

```
console.log(document.cookie)
```

I'm only getting the 1st of the key value pairs 
    Name = escape(name);

Why am I not getting Value="+escape(value) - Can I not set multiple key value pairs in a single statement:

document.cookie = "key1 ="+value1+"key2="+value2 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only write/update one cookie (a single name-value pair) in one statement.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#Syntax :

> `document.cookie = newCookie;`
>
> In the code above newCookie is a string of form key=value. Note that
>   you can only set/update a single cookie at a time using this method.

To add multiple pairs, try this:

```
var pairs = [
  {"name" : "foo", "value" : "foobar", "expires" : "Tue, 23 Jun 2015 19:00:00 GMT"},
  {"name" : "baz", "value" : 1198, "expires" : "Wed, 24 Jun 2015 12:00:00 GMT"}
];
pairs.forEach(function(pair) {
  document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(pair.name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(pair.value) + "; expires=" + pair.expires;
});
```